# Why applying the changes sometimes modify the text style in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word

In one of my Microsoft Word documents, applying the changes seem to modify the text style in Microsoft Word 2013. Am I misunderstanding something, or is it a bug?

In the example below, I select the text, apply "Body Text" on it, but when I preview the document after the changes are applied, the selected text becomes "heading 1". Why?

[image]

I use Microsoft Word 2013 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

The document can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4y6Mj_UZoTEREZKWW9FZFpDYlU).

Comment: I have just replicated this issue, very strange. Unfortunately I can't provide you with much insight. The only difference I can see is with paragraph markers on. The green area has two red paragraph markers after it, that are clearly getting removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this in Word 2010. There is no paragraph mark after the green text. Hit 'enter' at the end of the green text and it will be OK.

The reason is that this document has track changes on and there are two removed paragraphs after the green text. Press Ctrl + * to see them. You currently view the document with markup, so the removed paragraph marks are visible (in a sense - making empty lines), but when you change markup (in Review menu) to "no markup", they will be hidden and the green text will join the "FUNDING STATEMENT" paragraph and its style (Heading 1), showing the real current contents of the document.